# Plot matrix with custom bins

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I have a rfm matrix of the following form with recency score on x axis and frequency+monetary score on y-axis

```
      1     2     3     4     5
 1   68    172   600   400   119
 2   600   300   100   90     9
 3   100   200   1277  100  1014
 4   550   168   422   900   900
 5   1345  450   400   225   67
```

I am trying to recreate an plot/image similar to this

[image]

from [this article](https://www.putler.com/rfm-analysis/) using image and image2d with no success. How can I go about re-creating such an image?

Edit:Changed the numbers of the matrix to correspond to the numbers on the image

Comment: `image(your_matrix)` will color tiles based on values, but I think you're ultimately after something more complicated. The problem here is that it's unclear how the color scale[s] are supposed to work. Have you made any progress so far?

Comment: I want to combine cells in the matrix above to form respective buckets and the number in a bucket is the sum of the numbers in the corresponding cells. For example, lost bucket is (4,1)+(5,1)+(5,2) and the number in the plot/image should be 550+1345+450.

Comment: Then you've got some munging to do before you can visualize anything. You need to build a mask of which locations are grouped, so they can be summed.